# How to Convert a data-list(each value available in bracket) into the python list form?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data list available in below format:

```
AA = [['Monday'],['Tuesday'],['Wednesday'],['Thursday'],['Friday'],['Saturday'],['Sunday']]
```

I am trying to convert into the list format by using below

```
list(AA)
```

but it does't help me to get expected output as below. `list(AA)` is returning with same value as AA

Expected output:

```
AA= ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
```

how can I achieve expected output by using any python command?

Comment: Use `list(chain.from_iterable(AA))`. `from itertools import chain`.

Comment: new_list = [i[0] for i in AA]